# Does Google forms reveal identity of the person filling the form to the person who created the form?

Tags: google-forms, privacy

If I fill a Google Form hosted by someone, will my email id/account name be visible to whoever created the form?

If yes, is there a way to hide it?

Comment: What about Logging out?

Comment: @Ángel Some forms don't allow you to fill the forms while not being logged in

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the settings used when the form was created.

[This link](https://zapier.com/blog/google-forms-tips/) describes the settings in detail.

As a rule of thumb, if you have to login to your Google account to fill in the form, there's a possibility your email is being recorded.

Besides for your email no other identifying details are recorded, but for most, or many?, our email gives away our full identify.

The only proposed solution is to create a Gmail account specifically for filling in forms. (I didn't study the ToS of Gmail to see if this is allowed.)

Comment: While creating a new Gmail account, they ask for a phone number to verify (using SMS OTP) that you are not a robot. Do you know if Google stores the phone number after verify the OTP? i.e. is the phone number tied to the throwaway email account?

Comment: @user93353 yes, _Google_ keeps that number "for the security of your account", e.g. so that they could send an OTP there if they detect a suspicious login.

Comment: @angel - thank you. Will the number be revealed to the person who created the Google Forms questionnaire?